# Removing left margin for SlideShow

Tags: slideshows, user-interface

I would like to have a simple presentation with visualisations in Manipulate. For this purpose, I am using the toolbar from Palettes -> Classic Slide Shows. What I want is basically the whole screen to be taken by the title and Manipulate window. However, in the SlideShow view environment, Mathematica makes the left margin used for the cell labels very large – see the area highlighted by the red rectangle in the screenshot: [image: the left margin]
Is there a way to make this left margin smaller or remove the column completely? I turned the cell labels off by `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowCellLabel -> False]`, and I also tried lowering some other options I found in Option Inspector like `CellLabelMargins`, `CellFrameMargins` or `CellFrameLabelMargins`, but those have no significant effect.

Comment: Hello, Have you found a solution for this problem? It also bothers me.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find any good solution. If I remember correctly, I didn't find even a bad one for that matter :(